# PHP mail function (2)

Tags: email, sendmail, php

Hi I am using php mail function to send mails from my contact section. But the mails are not geting me. If i use gmail id its working but if I use any other email ids like `hr@sbnphpjobs.com` not geting.

Comment: They could be getting blocked as spam, have you checked your junk folder in your other email accounts? Can you check the server's outgoing mail log to see if the receiving server knocks back the emails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to use [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) or [Swift Mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) in combination with a smtp server (e.g. gmail). Mail send from php (mail()) is often seen as spam by a lot of spamfilters...

Answer (score 2):

Your smtp server might only send email to a white list of domain name. I had the same issue with a customer smtp. We bought another solution to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you get a chance to check mail logs? There can be a hint to why mails are not going through. If you are running your own server, then a dedicated IP will make sure that you are not having an ip that is blocked by anti spam databases.