# Wher to place my personal email address in the PHP code below

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form

currently, I am using a lightweight contact form WordPress plugin. In that plugin developer mentioned to place email address somewhere in the code above. Right now its I am getting all my emails to WordPress default email, please help.

```
wp_mail( get_bloginfo('admin_email'), $subject, $fullmsg, $headers );
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP mail function (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553765/php-mail-function-2)

Answer (score 0):

Check on wp_mail() doc page:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/

You can set `from` value inside headers array.

```
<?php
// assumes $to, $subject, $message have already been defined earlier...

$headers[] = 'From: Me Myself <me@example.net>';
$headers[] = 'Cc: John Q Codex <jqc@wordpress.org>';
$headers[] = 'Cc: iluvwp@wordpress.org'; // note you can just use a simple email address

wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
?>
```